# Hello! I dont understand how is right use word "component" in sourse Images (WPF) and I have problem with this item

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, path, uri

When I write the source of the image in my application (WPF) in the XAML file I have a problem with the path. In this way:

```
pack://application:,,,/Registration_and_Login_Forms/Images/key-icon.png
```

I do not have a problem, but I need to use this:

```
pack://application:,,,/Registration_and_Login_Forms;component/Images/key-icon.png
```

because without it I have problem with `<customcontrols>` tags in another xaml file. And if I paste the component I get the error that "could not load file or assembly".

I tried using another way to get a strong path like writing `pack://application: +` I writing the full path to the image + and pasting the word "component" to different places in this way and etc.

```
<PasswordBox.Background>
    <ImageBrush ImageSource="pack://application:,,,/Registration_and_Login_Forms;component/Images/key-icon.png"
                                Stretch="None"
                                AlignmentX="Left"/>
</PasswordBox.Background>
```

```
<customcontrols:BindablePasswordBox Password="{Binding Password}"
                                    Height="28"
                                    Margin="0,5,0,0">
</customcontrols:BindablePasswordBox>
```

Comment: I watch this video about MVVM Patterns "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FGqj4q09NtA&ab_channel=RJCodeAdvanceEN" and I have problem at 14 minute

Comment: Why  do you have a semicolon in the URL?

Comment: This is normal syntax for Uri component

Comment: @jdweng Semicolon is OK here, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/app-development/pack-uris-in-wpf

Comment: You assembly name is `Registration_and_Login_Forms`? The File has Build Action `Resource`?

Comment: No, the assembly name is WPF_Application and I don't have Build Action in this file